# Feathers with mongoose - delete from multiple collections

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, feathersjs

I am trying to have my feather.js api delete all the tasks belonging to a user when that user is 
deleted. Ultimately i am trying to build a delete account functionality

Users model:

```
// users-model.js - A mongoose model
//
// See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html
// for more of what you can do here.
module.exports = function (app) {
  const modelName = 'users';
  const mongooseClient = app.get('mongooseClient');
  const schema = new mongooseClient.Schema({

    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    password: { type: String },
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  // This is necessary to avoid model compilation errors in watch mode
  // see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-deleteModel
  if (mongooseClient.modelNames().includes(modelName)) {
    mongooseClient.deleteModel(modelName);
  }
  return mongooseClient.model(modelName, schema);

};
```

Tasks model:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const modelName = 'tasks';
  const mongooseClient = app.get('mongooseClient');
  const { Schema } = mongooseClient;
  const schema = new Schema(
    {
      text: { type: String, required: true },
      description: { type: String },
      completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      dueAt: { type: Date, default: null},
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
  );

  // This is necessary to avoid model compilation errors in watch mode
  // see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-deleteModel
  if (mongooseClient.modelNames().includes(modelName)) {
    mongooseClient.deleteModel(modelName);
  }
  return mongooseClient.model(modelName, schema);
};
```

In my users.hooks.js i tried adding the following in the after section:

```
 after: {
    all: [
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect("password"),
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    async remove(context) {
      const user = context.result;

      await context.app.service("tasks").remove(null, {
        query: { user: user._id },
      });
    },
  },
```

When i try this it give me a method not allowed error (405), any help with where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out!

to help others, its important to add multi: true to the service where multiple entities will be deleted (in my case tasks)